# Bash: Delete the first element of a list stored in a variable

Tags: bash, list, find

I'm using `Dirlist=$(find $1 -type d)` to get a list of the subdirectories of the directory given as the `$1` argument, but I need to eliminate from `Dirlist` the first element of the list (the directory `$1` itself). Someone can tell me how can I do it, please?

Comment: You need `Dirlist="..."` or `Dirlist=(...)`

Answer (score 4):

You can add `-mindepth 1` option:

```
find $1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```